# Convert Joomla website to documentation in PDF, CHM

Tags: html, pdf, joomla, documentation, documentation-generation

Currently I have a website made ​​in Joomla that contains documentation about some software (LogicalDOC) in 3 languages.

http://help.logicaldoc.com/

I need to convert the various sections in the corresponding PDF manuals.
So Installation Guide should be converted in a PDF, as well as the other sections: Users Guide, Administrator Guide and Workflow Guide (in the top menu).

I would like to know if there is a software or a different way (plugin) to convert the website in PDF
with navigation menu and possibly also to have the document in CHM format.

I have found a plugin **ebook Factory**
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/print-a-pdf/19294
but since it's for Joomla 3 and the website to convert uses an older version I can't try it.

Comment: Your website is not Joomla 3, it is 1.5. Your question's title is wrong. The plugin won't work in your website. Whatever the case, you might want to consider upgrading the website to J3.

Comment: Thanks @FFrewin I agree with you, it is absolutely necessary to upgrade to Joomla 3

Comment: Unfortunately, even if wanted ebook Factory doesn't not meet our requirements, in fact it is able to generate a PDF by selecting single articles or per category. 
The major requirement is the ability to replicate the website navigation with its menu starting from a specific path

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use (sniping tool) on windows or equivalent tool on your platform and take snapshot pictures of the manual Pages. If you can turn your screen 90 degrees to portrait mode then the format of the pages will look better than widescreen. If you want to include Navigation i think you will need a Full Version of Acrobat or Similar

Free Online tool to turn a collection of JPG pictures into a PDF file.

http://www.convert-jpg-to-pdf.net/

for CHM search the Net to see if you can find a free pdf to chm converter.

Comment: Indeed, this could be a solution, but in reality I was looking for an automation tool that would allow me to automate the process.

Comment: Also the documentation website that I have to convert statically in PDF contains perhaps a hundred pages in 3 languages, so a total of 300 pages. In addition that website is updated frequently

Comment: well you can print the pages to pdf using Prince -- princexml.com/samples -- but its pricey. For non-commercial use if you dont mind the logo on the first page its free. i think you can print PHP pages too but i never used it.